# Most efficient way to tile budding amethyst?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

While it isn't possible to place, craft, or move budding amethyst in vanilla, many mods allow the player to do one or more of these things. Assuming that the player is able to freely place budding amethyst, what is the best pattern to place it in to allow for the maximum amethyst yield in the least amount of space?

Comment: So you want to know what the most efficient amethyst farm is? Because the more space the more amethyst that can be generated

Comment: @DialFrost not necessarily a farm, just a tiling of budding amethyst to pack as many fully exposed (i.e. able to grow amethyst crystals on all faces) budding amethyst blocks into, for example, a 16 by 16 by 16 space.

Comment: The big drawback of tightly packing the amythyst like that is that it leaves no room for harvester machines and automation of the farm, unless you use some cheaty modded contraptions that harvest it remotely, or harvest it manually (in which case the optimal layout makes access to it really hard.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an optimal way (and possibly the only optimal way) to tile budding amethyst. It leaves no empty blocks within the tiling, and no budding amethyst blocks with obstructed faces. The tiling repeats cubically every 7 blocks. Here is a screenshot showing one 7x7x7 unit.

[image: Image showing optimal tiling]

Here's a layer by layer view.

[image: Layer by layer view]

And [here](https://lostxor.com/files/amethyst_tiling.nbt) is a structure file of the tiling. ([Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20240305050543/https://lostxor.com/files/amethyst_tiling.nbt)  in case my website goes down)

(Tiling taken from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666138) fairly similar Mathematics Stack Exchange question)